# fullcalendar nextDayThreshold not working. It shown one day less with '00:00:00'

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I can't get the correct visualization on fullcalendar v4. I'm using this format `'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'` for dates and calendar events or select ranges with '00:00:00' time are shown with one day less.

[image]

I tried with `nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00"` but it seems to be excluding and doesn't works with `'00:00:00'`.

One option is to modify all end dates from `'00:00:00'` to `'23:59:59'`, but isn't a good solution.

here there is my calendar definition:

```
calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],
    locale: 'es',
    selectable: true,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
    displayEventTime : false,
    nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00",
    views: {
        list: {
            displayEventTime : true,
        }
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prevYear,prev,next,nextYear,today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
    },
    events: [{
        daysOfWeek: [0,6],
        rendering:"background",
        color: "#ff9f89",
        overLap: false,
        allDay: true
    }],
    events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/calendar/getCalendarEvents',
            data: {
                token: localStorage.token,
                userFilter: userFilter
            },
            success: function(events) {
                successCallback(events);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (info) {
        startDateSelected = moment(info.startStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected = moment(info.endStr).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventClick: function(info) { 
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventResize: function(info) {
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
    },
    eventDrop: function(info) {
        evTittleSelected = info.event.title;
        startDateSelected =  moment(info.event.start).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        endDateSelected =  moment(info.event.end).format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss");
        console.log('de ' + startDateSelected + ' a ' + endDateSelected);
    }
});
```

any idea?

Comment: Are you thinking it's a bug? It's not, because end dates are treated as **exclusive** (see docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object).

Comment: not a bug, but the idea is to know if there is any method to change that with any kind of trick or something

Comment: The only trick really is what you already mentioned: modify the event dates - either by changing the times as you mentioned, or incrementing the end date by 1 day. Either that or you change the behaviour in the fullCalendar source code.

Comment: ok so I will do like the example. Thanks